# How to find tags that aren't empty with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I got this code, but I just want it to grab p-tags that aren't empty, how do I do that?

```
doc.css('p').first(3).each do |paragraph|
  puts raw(paragraph)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select`:

```
doc.css('p').select{ |n| n.inner_text }.each do |paragraph|
  puts raw(paragraph)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter if you remove the blank tags altogether, you can try something like this:

```
doc.css('p').each do |node|
  node.remove if node.inner_text == ''
end
```

Not very elegant, but add this before your code and you won't get any blank nodes in subsequent queries.